# Проблема с дешифровкой русских символов

Tags: python, python-3.x

Сделал по гайду кодировку/декодировку сообщений по ключу и цифры/англ. символы кодируются нормально, но русские символы не могут декодироваться обратно

```py
def encode(key, clear):
    enc = []
    for i in range(len(clear)):
        key_c = key[i % len(key)]
        enc_c = chr((ord(clear[i]) + ord(key_c)) % 256)
        enc.append(enc_c)
    return base64.urlsafe_b64encode("".join(enc).encode()).decode()

def decode(key, enc):
    dec = []
    enc = base64.urlsafe_b64decode(enc).decode()
    for i in range(len(enc)):
        key_c = key[i % len(key)]
        dec_c = chr((256 + ord(enc[i]) - ord(key_c)) % 256)
        dec.append(dec_c)
    return "".join(dec)
```

И вместо "сори не дешифруется" получаем "A>@8 =5 45H8DAC5BAO"
Может ошибка в коде декодера или русские символы так кодировать не выйдет?

Comment: Для 1251 это будет работать. Для юникода - не будет. Очень похоже что у вас символы таки с юникода и вы старшие 8 бит теряете.

Comment: и называть функции именами встроенных методов строк не стоит.

Comment: Попробуйте 256 поменять на 65536. Надо или работать с 8-битовой кодировкой, там 1251 например, или UTF-8 на крайний случай, или учитывать что у вас символ 16 бит, а не 8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сразу переводить строку в байты и работать с ними. Тогда точно не будет потерь после получения остатка от деления на 256.

```
def encode(key, clear):
    enc = []
    clear_bytes = clear.encode()
    key_bytes = key.encode()
    for i in range(len(clear_bytes)):
        key_c = key_bytes[i % len(key_bytes)]
        enc_c = (clear_bytes[i] + key_c) % 256
        enc.append(enc_c)
    return base64.urlsafe_b64encode(bytes(enc)).decode()

def decode(key, enc):
    dec = []
    enc_bytes = base64.urlsafe_b64decode(enc)
    key_bytes = key.encode()
    for i in range(len(enc_bytes)):
        key_c = key_bytes[i % len(key_bytes)]
        dec_c = (enc_bytes[i] - key_c) % 256
        dec.append(dec_c)
    return bytes(dec).decode()
```